# Make MyLocation looks like an arrow like Google Map, instead of a blue dot in Google Maps API V2?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I would like a simple app to display current user location, but GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); only show a blue dot. So how to replace that blue dot to an arrow like google map app? The arrow will rotate when user rotate device.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry the answer is no, maybe Google don't allowed us make an app as good as Google Map.

Comment: Thought so.. Tried hard with no luck. Finally working on own marker. And combining both gps n compass to determine the location n direction best.